# Why can't I modify my comment form using hook_form_alter

Tags: theming, forms, comments

I have enabled comments for a custom node type.

I am trying to theme that comment form using `hook_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state)` (For example, I'd like to remove the label of the `comment_body` form field)

To do that, I use the following function:

```
function MYTHEME_form_comment_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
    $form['comment_body']['und']['#title'][0] = '';
}
```

However in the output the title of the form field is still there:

[image: actual output]

Here's the markup:

[image]

The value of `$form` does not correspond to what I am used to see. Here's a screenshot from my debugger:

[image]

Comment: Why `[LANGUAGE_NONE]` in your code, and yet you do not expand `['und']` in the debugger? I mean, if that's the part that matters, why not to show it to us?

Comment: You show "MYTHEME" as hook in your function name, you do that in template.php? You should try to do that in a custom module.

Comment: hook_form_BASEID_form_alter in theme is almost equivalent with module, it just gets called after the module hooks.

Comment: @Molot: Good point. I updated the screenshot.

Comment: OK now seems you are trying to update what should be updated. Is your hook fired at all?

Comment: @Molot: Yes it is. I have the debugger breakpoint set to within the hook.

Comment: You should use `[LANGUAGE_NONE]` rather than `['und']` - it's the same but you should prefer constants over direct values. But anyway, it seems you have a question a bit too interesting. You seem to edit what you should, `&` are where they should be, everything seems all right...

Comment: I generated quick installation and the function from custom active theme works fine. template.php containing function tests_omega_form_comment_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
 $form['comment_body']['und'][0]['#title'] = 'test';
}

Comment: There seems to be 2 "#title"-values try clearing both of them.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the label "Comment*" is not from comment_body [container](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#container) wrapper, then again comment_body shouldnt be of type container.

Most likely the actual comment field is somewhere not visible of your debug screenshot. This is because drupal core comment module form doesnt use normal form api structure where containers only reference children and reverse. Instead the actual field is placed directly to container. Luckily drupal_render has no problem with neither structure.

Removing the label should not require specifying language on the actual field. It should be as easy as

`$form['comment_body']['#title']='';`

Instead with funky comment form render array you need to specify language of the containers sub items, hence the path transforms to

`$form['comment_body'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['#title']=''`

Comment: As you can see in his debugger screenshot, there is no `$form['comment_body']['#title']` present, so setting it up hardly can help.

Comment: The example describes method usable if the comment_body would actually be a normal field. In this case the actual field most likely exists at $form['comment_body'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['#title'] = '';

Comment: @user20301: No idea why your response was downvoted. I consider it quite helpful. In any case I noticed that the reference to the field was incorrect. I tried your approach (`$form['comment_body'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['#title']=''`) but the Label _Comment*_ still appears. It seems that I'll have to go deeper and debug `drupal_render` to see what's happening. Or hide the label via CSS (which feels hackish)

Answer (score 0):

I Was attempting to add a placeholder for the comment_body field and after struggling through this a bit, was able to figure out that the changes will take in affect if you utilize the "value" array key like so:

```
$form['comment_body'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']['#title']='foo bar';
```