# How to use form API to edit sub form that is added to user_register_form

Tags: 7, forms

I need to alter a [Redhen Contact](http://drupal.org/project/redhen) form when it is attached to the user registration form.  More generically, I need to alter a sub form.  The form is added to `user_register_form()` via `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()` in rendhen_contact.module:1029.  (I don't think this is specific to Redhen's implementation; I'm just providing this as a reference point.)

The first issue I encountered was that the hook implementation in redhen_contact.module hadn't occurred when my hook was called.  In a custom module, I used `hook_module_implements_alter()` to resolve that (see screenshot at bottom for `kpr()`).  With that I'm still unable to alter, for example, the `#title` attribute of `field_agency_interest`.  Even if I do `$form['redhen_contact]['form']['field_agency_interest']['und']['#title']` or `...['und'][0]['title']` it doesn't change.

I tried using `$form['#after_build'][] = 'module_callback_name'` but I can't edit the sub form elements.

[image: screenshot of kpr()]

How can I alter a sub form added to a form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across this: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/129617/7595, which identifies that you have to dig a bit deeper into the element; specifically the `['value']` element.

So, for editing a subform this will work:

```
function hook_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['redhen_contact']['form']['field_agency_interest']['#pre_render'][] = '_field_agency_interest_pre_render';
}
function _field_agency_interest_pre_render($element) {
  $element[$element['#language']][0]['value']['#description'] = '<a href="test">Test</a>';  

  return $element;
}
```

I'll note again that I'm using `#pre_render` because the RedHen module hook was being called after this one and this ensures everything has been added to the form prior to making changes.

Answer (score 0):

You probably forgot to reference the `$form` variable ("`&$form`").
The alternative to `#after_build` would be `#pre_render`, which misses `$form_state` but should generally be preferred for changes that only affect the rendering of a form.

Comment: Thanks @ciss.  The callbacks for `#after_build` and `#pre_render` return the element (or form) so referencing isn't used here.  `#pre_render` doesn't work either though.  I am able to change the title for `$form['redhen_contact']` (which is a fieldset) but I can't seem to do anything with the fields.

Comment: I was referring to hook_form_alter(). A common mistake is to forget the argument reference, which makes changes to the $form array ineffective, including any added callbacks.